# Android BLE - Unable to Write to ESP32

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been trying to get BLE to work properly. I am needing to connect to an ESP32 and send wifi credentials for the device's initial setup. I have attempted to find code that functions and works correctly but have been unable to do so.

My overall goal is to have the user input the SSID and password, then the next screen called `BLEScanner` then has a scanner where the user will select the device and press connect. Once the device connects, I am trying to have the application handle the data transfer without the user needing to provide any more input. In the code below, the user inputs the wifi credentials in a previous view that passes the information to `BLEScanner`.

I am running the application on a LG Nexus 5. It is running Android 6.0.1

I am attempting to use the following code to write to a Gatt characteristic after I discover it. When I get the list, I am parsing through the characteristics that I have discovered and attempting to write to all of the characteristics. To write to the characteristics, I am doing the following. `gattCharacteristic` is type `BluetoothGattCharacteristic`. `bluetoothGatt` is of type `BluetoothGatt`. HomeBoyEugene is the SSID of a local coffee shop, which is why is is listed in the code at the end of the question.

```
gattCharacteristic.setValue("SSID_AS_STRING");
gattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
```

I have noticed some strange behavior while trying to get this to work correctly. The first is that when I perform a permissions check, `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)` does not return as `PERMISSION_GRANTED`. I have tried to include methods to grant the permissions but they are not working. I have also included the permission in my Manifest, using the following block.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

This is the segment of code that I am using to try to get permissions for `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT`:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BLEScanner.this, new String[] { BLUETOOTH_CONNECT }, 0);
```

Okay here's where we get into the confusing behavior. I'm using the following block to read the value of the characteristic and convert it into a string so I can print it into Logcat in Android Studio

```
byte[] hex2 = gattCharacteristic.getValue();
String str2 = new String(hex2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

When I perform this operation, it is returning the value that I am attempting to write to it, i.e. `SSID_AS_STRING`. However, the ESP32 is not recognizing a write event. The ESP will display on its console whenever a write event occurs and we have verified that the ESP code works with other third party apps. I am trying to figure out now why it would seem that I am writing to the characteristics on my end and that I am able to read the value that I am writing to it, but the ESP is not actually writing to it.

Below is a large snippet of the code. I have a lot of print statements throughout, but figured you would like to see everything in context.

```
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
        if (gattServices == null) return;
        String mWriteValue = "Testing";
        Log.i("gattServices", String.valueOf(gattServices));

        // Loops through available GATT Services.
        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {

            final String uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
            System.out.println("Service discovered: " + uuid);
            BLEScanner.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("service", "Service discovered: " + uuid + "\n");
                }
            });
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                    gattService.getCharacteristics();

            // Loops through available Characteristics.
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                    gattCharacteristics) {

                final String charUuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                //System.out.println("Characteristic discovered for service: " + charUuid);

                gattCharacteristic.setValue("HomeBoyEugene");
                gattCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i("Permission Check","Checking Permissions for writeCharacteristic");
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BLEScanner.this, new String[] { BLUETOOTH_CONNECT }, 0);
                }

                bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);

                Log.i("characteristics", "Characteristic discovered for service: " + charUuid + "\n");
                Log.i("read characteristics", String.valueOf(bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic)));
                byte[] hex2 = gattCharacteristic.getValue();
                String str2 = new String(hex2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                Log.i("value", String.valueOf(str2));
                Log.i("spacer", "----------------------------------------");
            }
            Log.i("BREAK","=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");

            // Second loop to try to read what was written to the characteristics in the previous for loop
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                    gattCharacteristics) {
                byte[] hex2 = gattCharacteristic.getValue();
                String str2 = new String(hex2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                Log.i("value", String.valueOf(str2));
            }

            Log.i("BREAK","=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=/");
        }
    }
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. I don't really know how to word what I'm asking but I'm out of ideas on how to continue with debugging this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a useful log output by any chance?

Comment: What are you looking for in the log output? I can probably make it happen if you tell me what you're wanting to see

Comment: I expect to see some kind of error when using BLE. You say it does not work, right?

Comment: I just realized you are writing to and reading from the device using loops. This could be the problem! BLE communication is asynchronous, you need to wait until you receive a [BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicWrite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)) callback before attempting another write

Comment: Okay gotcha. Could you provide an example of how a function that would wait for a callback before attempting to write again? I don't fully understand how BLE works and all of the details behind callbacks. The reason I'm confused is that there are no errors being thrown while running the application. Also, thanks so much for the help, I really do appreciate it

Comment: Take a look at the official android documentation regarding [reading characteristics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-ble-data#read) or follow one of the many android BLE tutorials online. I had a good experience using [this one](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-3-117d3a8aee23) but it might be difficult to incorporate it into your existing code since it explains how to split your BLE code from the rest

Comment: As Michael said, operations are asynchronous: connect => wait for BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange => call gatt.discoverServices() => wait for onServicesDiscovered => request read/write => wait for onCharacteristicChanged/onCharacteristicWrite. Example: https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLEProof-collection

Comment: Also note that BLE libraries for ESP32 take a lot of program space, so it's possible that if you use both BLE and WiFi, it might be not enough program space in ESP32, so be sure that to compiler doesn't show memory warnings.